# How to configure AWS API Gateway to get a pdf response?

Tags: django, python-requests, aws-api-gateway, aws-code-deploy

[Response from server which works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHhDI.jpg)PDF is received from the server with response headers

```
Content-type: application/pdf
```

and

```
Content-dispositon : attachment
```

whereas from API Gateway the PDF response gets corrupted with a change in file size as well. I was able to configure Method Response to application/pdf. Though I still have no solution for content disposition header which does not appear in the response header of API Gateway.

[Response from API Gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrGVJ.jpg)

Content-Disposition comes empty too

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information, specifically:

Where does your API Gateway proxy to? Lambda? Another HTTP server?
A screenshot/dump of configs of your API Gateway configuration

Comment: The API Gateway points to a docker container where my API's are deployed (Django). The Server provides the response as a pdf of size 317 KB. Above the container I have put API GATEWAY so as to encapsulate my origin server name.